# WPML: getting page title in different language

Tags: multi-language, plugin-wpml

i'm running my web in english and german using the WPML plugin.
my question:
when in english mode - is it possible getting the page_title() but in german?

thanks

Comment: Since this is a premium plugin, it's not likely that you're going to get a great answer here. You might search the WPML documentation here http://wpml.org/documentation/ or buy a support license for $30 here: http://wpml.org/purchase/ They actually have a pretty reasonable setup there, and would be able to give you much better answers much more quickly. Also: free upgrades!

Comment: I would recommend putting questions and answers here, this is an independent community and you do not have to pay to be able to access the forum. Yes, I am paying customer of WPML, but I have their forum implementation and access policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say the original language of your site is english, then when visiting a german post you would return the title of the corresponding english post like that :

```
// Get the post ID of original post
$original_ID = icl_object_id( $post->ID, 'post', false, 'en' );

// Get original post title
$original_title = get_the_title( $original_ID );
```

Hope that helps, in any case check out the documentation for [icl_object_id();](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/language-dependent-ids/)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for that mike23, was a lifesaver for me today. However that exact code didn't work for me, I did have to do some modifications in order to get it to work in my situation which may be due to a newer version of the WPML plugin.

I had to change:

```
$original_ID = icl_object_id( $post->ID, 'post', false, 'en' );
```

to:

```
$original_ID = icl_object_id( $post->ID, 'any', false, 'en' );
```

Notice that the only change is 'post' -> 'any'. It's a small change but made a world of difference as any other type that I entered would not work for me. Hope this helps someone that runs into the same issue.

PS: I found that the 'any' type could be used by going to the file where that function is created: /wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/template-functions.php. When in the file search for icl_object_id().